# Ruby code in development mode

Tags: ruby

How am I supposed to use ruby with development mode, which is not require me to restart my ruby process every time I made changes , just like Rails development mode, when I made changes no need to restart the code and the new code will be applied directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use gem shotgun for webapps server  [Reference](http://ruby.about.com/od/sinatra/a/sinatra5.htm)

I dont think you can go ahead without restarting the app for changes!!!

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help , anyways then how come that we don't need to restart anything if we made any changes with Rails framework ?  there must be something to do with ruby files , don't u think so ?

Comment: ruby is intrepreted so its compiled and run each time unlike java where we need to compile the code first and then run!!! In rails too while the page refreshes only the dynamic elements change and not by restarting the server!!

Comment: @eki: I guess this is because in Rails you only keep running the web server. But for the actual application, a Ruby instance is run for each HTTP request. So your application itself is restarted in fact.

Comment: oh that make sense now, thanks for the explanation here undur_gongor

Answer (score 0):

Using  `load` rather than `require` allows you to reload a file that you've edited since you've started the Ruby script.

That's what development mode does in Rails.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to keep restarting your app in every instance, for example when you change you controllers and views you wont have to.

If you change your routes or migrations you will need to restart for that.

Comment: I assume, eki is talking about a non-rails application.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I'm not talking about Rails project here , rather than classic ruby file , lets say that you create hello.rb file and just changed some stuff, it will not be applied before restarting it

Comment: you probably need to have a guard script to check if the file modifies and that have it rerun the script.